# Why does mysqli_fetch_array() return array double the size?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, lamp

I'm doing a very simple php statement such as

```
print_r($my_rec);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($my_rec);
echo "\nP_Id " . $row['P_Id'] . ' Length ' . sizeof($row) . "\n";
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($my_rec);
echo "\nP_Id " . $row['P_Id'] . ' Length ' . sizeof($row) . "\n";
```

Now when print_r prints to the screen, it reports that there are only 16 fields/columns in each array. This is true. However when I fetch an array, it gives me double the fields. In other words the array is repeating itself which doesn't make sense. Example ...

I have in my database

```
 Col1  Col2
 "hi1" "bye1"
```

When I do

```
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($my_rec);
 foreach($row as $x){
       echo $x . "\n";
 }
```

It will print

```
 hi1
 hi1
 by2
 by2
```

Why am I getting this behavior?

Comment: RTLM: http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array, the "RETURN VALUES" section in particular.

Comment: @MarcB What does the L mean

Comment: `Linked`, since `F'ing` was judged too harsh to use by some people here.

Comment: Also check out http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc for avoiding including the position-indexes.

Comment: I don't understand why I'm being down voted. I read the php manual and didn't get why I was getting double arrays. Then I go onto stackoverflow to ask a question and I'm docked for not understanding the manual. You people ruin stackoverflow. This isn't a site made for people who know what they are doing. Otherwise why else would anyone ask questions here. I know a ton of people who avoid forums like these because people like you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it also includes an array filled with columns's positions (i.e: 0, 1, 2, 3 and id, username, password, email). Both `id` and `0` hold the same data.

If you only want the string indexes, you can use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` (http://php.net/mysqli_fetch_assoc)